# grep / ripgrep - limit number of characters

Tags: linux, grep, ripgrep

I have a set of very big files that I want to search for a specific string.

I know that the string is going to be present very close to the beginning of the file. It's usually at the very start of the file. When it's not, it's within the first 1k bytes.

Is there a way to tell grep / ripgrep to search only the first N bytes (or characters)?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762274/can-i-grep-only-the-first-n-lines-of-a-file might b helpful.